# Symfony Flex: Override FOSUser login form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-flex

I read up on two ways to override the FOSUser login form:

1. place template file in `app/Resources/` [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html)
2. override the Controller in a child Bundle [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)

However, with [Symfony Flex](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-demo.html) the project structure changed substantially.

As for option #1: There is no `app/Resources` folder anymore. I store my templates in `/templates`.

Regarding option #2: There is no AppBundle anymore.

Now, I extended FOSUser's security Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\SecurityController as BaseController;

class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function renderLogin(array $data)
    {
        return $this->render('/Admin/Login/index.html', $data);
    }
}
```

The application still renders the FOSUserBundle form. I have a feeling that I have to register the avobe controller somehow. In the FOSUser config, there is no directive for that. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think you should also override the default /login route, try to point new route with path "/login" to your renderLogin method on your controller.

Comment: Did you clear the cache and change the method to protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Symfony 4, you just need put the file in /templates/bundles/FosUserBundle

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I think you followed the good path but forgot to change your config. You need to tell fosuser to use a different form file.

Check [this file](https://github.com/artandor/diabetehelper/blob/master/app/config/config.yml), line 106 & 109 :)

I didn't check this solution with flex, but a friend of mine did with symfony 4 and it worked just fine.